# cross database foreign key, 1215 error

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I tried to create db1 table read_x_tag_0 column foreign key db2 column below is my code,  not sure am I doing right?  it showing 1215 error, can't find why?

database 'read'
table 'read_x_tag_0'

```
CREATE TABLE `read_x_tag_0` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `read_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tag_0_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tag_0_sequence` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `read_id` (`read_id`),
  KEY `tag_0_id` (`tag_0_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `read_x_tag_0_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`read_id`) REFERENCES `read` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `read_x_tag_0_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_0_id`) REFERENCES `tag_0`.`tag_0` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=76 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

database 'read'
table 'read'

```
CREATE TABLE `read` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `intro` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `sequence` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `visible` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '1:visible,0:invisible',
  `create_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `create_by` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `update_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `update_by` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

database 'tag_0'
table 'tag_0'

```
CREATE TABLE `tag_0` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `visible` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '1:visible,0:invisible',
  `sequence` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `create_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `create_by` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `update_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `update_by` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `subject` (`subject`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Is the table `read` relevant to this question?

Comment: ?? it just my table name

Comment: Why did you include that table in this question, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the foreign key. The only tables that are relevant are `read_x_tag_0` and `tag_0`.

Comment: I try to let `read_x_tag_0` relate  if table `read` delete row and `tag_0.tag_0` update, delete

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't put the `.` inside the backticks. The backticks escape all the characters inside, so it's not treated as a delimiter between the database and table name. It should be:

```
REFERENCES `db2`.`tag_0`
```

In your constraints, you're using the same name `read_x_tag_0` for both constraints. All constraints have to have different names, so rename one of them.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I changed but still get 1215 error

Comment: It works for me. Did you create `db2.tag_0` before creating `db1.read_x_tag_0`?

Comment: I copied your table definitions to my system and it worked fine. You must have done something different from what you posted in the question.

Comment: You have two constraints with the same name. That's not allowed.

Comment: I change to `read_x_tag_0_ibfk_1` and `read_x_tag_0_ibfk_2` but still get error 1215

Comment: Now your table names don't match. It should be `REFERENCES tag_0.tag_0`. There's no table named `tag_0_id`.

Comment: I copied your SQL, in the following order: `read.read`, `tag_0.tag_0`, `read.read_x_tag_0`. I didn't get any errors. Make sure you create the tables in that order.

Comment: So we basically spent an hour fixing all your typos. What an excellent use of my expertise.